# PHP output in HTML file

Tags: php

Ay guys,

I do know two possibilites to display PHP in HTML:

```
<?php function(); ?> or the shorter method <?= function(); ?>
```

But I often see something like {METHOD} or {OUTPUT} in the HTML part of bigger scripts f.e.:

```
<div class="test">{OUTPUT}</div>
```

In my opinion this is a way tidier. Could somebody tell me more about this?

Comment: This is called a template engine. `Twig`, `Smarty` or something else.

Comment: is it easy to implement this method without using external scripts like twig or smarty?

Comment: Easy is a relative word. Why reinvent the wheel? http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

Answer (score 0):

I have used php to generate html using the echo function and have used php inside html too.(If this clarifies your doubt in anyway)

1. echo $projectname; inside html file tags
2. echo the html file

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

When echoing data in HTML without a template engine, short tags are preferred as they look cleaner, and are easier to read. They're great when using control structures too: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

For short tags to work [short_open_tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) needs to be enabled.

The example you shown with the curly brackets is usually specific to a template engine such as [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/).

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method only with the function ECHO with double quotes :

1 - this works

```
$name = 'Mark';
echo "<div>GoodMorning {$name}</div>";
```

2 - this does not work

```
$name = 'Mark';
echo '<div>GoodMorning {$name}</div>';
```